# Wagmi useSigner hook doesn't work when url has a query parameter in a Next JS project

Tags: ethers.js, wagmi, rainbowkit

I am trying to use the `useSigner` hook from wagmi.

My project is a Next JS project and I am using the rainbow kit button to connect.

If I am at a page with a url like `localhost:3000` the signer loads at the time of page load, but if I am at a url like `localhost:3000?id=1`, the signer is null

You can [recreate the bug from here](https://github.com/Suhel-Kap/signer-issue)

My _app.tsx looks like this

```js
import {AppProps} from 'next/app';
import Head from 'next/head';
import '@rainbow-me/rainbowkit/styles.css';
import {
  getDefaultWallets,
  RainbowKitProvider,
  darkTheme
} from '@rainbow-me/rainbowkit';
import {
  configureChains,
  createClient,
  WagmiConfig,
} from 'wagmi';
import {alchemyProvider} from 'wagmi/providers/alchemy';
import {publicProvider} from 'wagmi/providers/public';
import {useState, useEffect} from "react";
import {polygonMumbai} from "@wagmi/chains";

export default function App(props: AppProps) {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  const {Component, pageProps} = props;
  const {chains, provider, webSocketProvider} = configureChains(
      [polygonMumbai],
      [
        alchemyProvider({apiKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_ALCHEMY_API_KEY!}),
        publicProvider()
      ]
  );
  const {connectors} = getDefaultWallets({
    appName: 'Dynamic Audio NFTs',
    chains
  });
  const wagmiClient = createClient({
    autoConnect: true,
    connectors,
    provider,
    webSocketProvider
  })


  return (
      <>
        <Head>
          <title>The Crypto Studio</title>
        </Head>
        <WagmiConfig client={wagmiClient}>
          <RainbowKitProvider chains={chains} theme={darkTheme()}>
                  <Component {...pageProps} />
          </RainbowKitProvider>
        </WagmiConfig>
      </>
  );
}
```

and this is the index.tsx

```js
import {ConnectButton} from "@rainbow-me/rainbowkit";
import {useSigner} from "wagmi";

export default function Home() {
  const {data: signer} = useSigner()
  console.log("signer", signer)

  return (
      <>
        <ConnectButton />
      </>
  )
}
```

the package.json

```json
{
  "name": "rainbow-kit",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@next/font": "13.0.7",
    "@rainbow-me/rainbowkit": "^0.8.1",
    "@types/node": "18.11.17",
    "@types/react": "18.0.26",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.0.9",
    "ethers": "^5.7.2",
    "next": "13.0.7",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "typescript": "4.9.4",
    "wagmi": "^0.9.4"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue has been resolved, the only thing that needs to be done here is that

```js
const {chains, provider, webSocketProvider} = configureChains(
      [polygonMumbai],
      [
        alchemyProvider({apiKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_ALCHEMY_API_KEY!}),
        publicProvider()
      ]
  );
  const {connectors} = getDefaultWallets({
    appName: 'Dynamic Audio NFTs',
    chains
  });
  const wagmiClient = createClient({
    autoConnect: true,
    connectors,
    provider,
    webSocketProvider
  })
```

needs to be placed outside the `App` function

so now, the `_app.tsx` would look something like

```js
const {chains, provider, webSocketProvider} = configureChains(
      [polygonMumbai],
      [
        alchemyProvider({apiKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_ALCHEMY_API_KEY!}),
        publicProvider()
      ]
  );
  const {connectors} = getDefaultWallets({
    appName: 'Dynamic Audio NFTs',
    chains
  });
  const wagmiClient = createClient({
    autoConnect: true,
    connectors,
    provider,
    webSocketProvider
  })
export default function App(props: AppProps) {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  const {Component, pageProps} = props;
  


  return (
      <>
        <Head>
          <title>The Crypto Studio</title>
        </Head>
        <WagmiConfig client={wagmiClient}>
          <RainbowKitProvider chains={chains} theme={darkTheme()}>
                  <Component {...pageProps} />
          </RainbowKitProvider>
        </WagmiConfig>
      </>
  );
}
```